# The Photon in Bosonic String Theory?

Tags: electromagnetism, photons, string-theory

As I understand it bosonic string theory describes the effects of gravity through interactions involving closed strings.

The wikipedia entry on [bosonic string theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosonic_string_theory) says that bosonic string theories with closed, oriented strings have the following particle states which represent long-range forces: tachyons (absent in superstring theory), gravitons, dilatons, antisymmetric tensor and a $U(1)$ vector boson.

Could the $U(1)$ vector boson be identified with the photon at low energies?

Comment: Yes$\mathrm{} $

Comment: Thanks! Is this why Kaluza-Klein theory can unify gravity and  electromagnetism using a 5-dimensional precursor of string theory with 1 dimension wrapped up in a circle?

Comment: @JohnEastmond KK theory has nothing to do with string theory even as a precursor. A simple field theory in 5 dimensions with a compact circle will give rise to a photon in 4 dimensions. No strings are needed for it.

Comment: @JohnEastmond Further to PraharMitra's comment, KKT's recovery of EM, the ["Kaluza-Klein miracle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaluza%E2%80%93Klein_theory#Field_equations_from_the_Kaluza_hypothesis), that has nothing to do with energy scales. What KKT does in modern terms is to interpret $A^\nu$ as a shift vector, then introduce a lapse function, the dilaton.